# JavaScript fetch to Django view: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch

I have a JavaScript fetch to call a URL to pass data into my Django view to update a value for the user.

**Error in views.py:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\Scry\apps\administration\views.py", line 47, in administration_users_page
    switchData = json.load(request)['switch']
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Error in browser:**

```
0
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/administration/users/JM/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const changeAdminUserAction = (id,data) => {
    console.log(data)
    fetch(`/administration/users/${id}/`,{
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({type: "adminUser", switch: data}),
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken' : csrfToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {location.reload()})
    .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
}
```

**views.py:**

```
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=kwargs.get('username'))
        
        switchType = json.load(request)['type']
        switchData = json.load(request)['switch']
        print(switchType, switchData)
        
        if switchType == 'adminUser':
            user.admin_user = switchData
        elif switchType == 'admindata':
            user.admin_data = switchData
        elif switchType == 'Status':
            if user.status == COMMON.USER_ACTIVE:
                user.status = COMMON.USER_SUSPENDED
            else:
                user.status = COMMON.USER_ACTIVE
            user.failed_logins = 0

        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({})
```

This is throwing an error at `switchData = json.load(request)['switch']`. I don't know why it is throwing the error there as the previous line `switchType = json.load(request)['type']` works as expected and returns the value that was passed to it.

`data` is a integer - either 1 or 0. I have tried make this value a string but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why this happens, but its clearly related to the form how you are reading your data. It will also break at `switchType = json.load(request)['type']` if you invert the lines (Seems to break while reading the second argument).

Data comes in as bytes, you can decode them into string ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/7100120)) and parse into JSON, this method worked well in my testing:

```
if request.method == 'PUT':
    decoded_bytes = request.body.decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(decoded_bytes)
    switchType = data['type']
    switchData = data['switch']
    print(switchType, switchData)
    ...

    return JsonResponse({})
```

Comment: An extention to your answer you don't have to decode `request.body` just pass it directly inside [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) it accepts **bytes**

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `json.load(request)['switch']` be `json.load(request.body)['switch']`?